# MySQL query to find most repeated items in each group

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Schema is

```
Hotel      (hotelNo, hotelName, city) 
Room      (roomNo, hotelNo, rtype, price) 
Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo) 
Guest      (guestNo, guestName, guestAddress)
```

and I want to write SQL query for most commonly booked room type for each hotel in Brookings ?(Brookings is a city)

I've tried many methods but none seems to work

```
select rtype
from room r natural
join hotel h
where rtype = (
        select distinct (rtype)
        from room r1 natural
        join booking
        where r1.hotelno = h.hotelno
        group by rtype
        having count(*) = (
                select max(c)
                from (
                    select count() as c
                    from room r2 natural
                    join booking
                    where r2.hotelno = h.hotelno
                    group by rtype
                    ) as x
                )
        )
group by h,
    hotelno
```

Comment: What is your sample data and what have you tried and didnt work out?

Comment: SELECT rType FROM Room r NATURAL JOIN Hotel h
WHERE rType = 
( 
 SELECT distinct(rType) FROM Room r1 NATURAL JOIN Booking
    WHERE r1.hotelNo= h.hotelNo
    GROUP BY rType
    HAVING count(*)=
    (
  SELECT max(c) FROM 
  (
   SELECT count(*) as c FROM Room r2 NATURAL JOIN Booking 
   WHERE r2.hotelNo= h.hotelNo
   GROUP BY rType
  ) AS X
 )
)
GROUP BY h,hotelNo;

Comment: and about the type of room it could be single or double

Comment: Please update your question with the query you posted in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
select *
from Room r
join hotel h on r.hotelNo = h.hotelNo
where r.rtype in (
        select r.rtype
        from Room r2
        join Booking b on r2.hotelNo = b.hotelNo
            and r2.roomNo = b.roomNo
        where r.hotelNo = r2.hotelNo
        group by r.rtype
        order by count(*) desc limit 1
        );
```